# Remove duplicate entries using bash, awk or sed

Tags: command-line, batch, search, duplicate

How can i search for duplicate data using batch? Goal is to remove duplicate "Changelist: XXXXX" entry from data.txt file. I'm kind of stuck, can somebody help me?

Please take a look at output.txt for desired output.

data.txt

```
====================================
 Changelist: 808298
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: A
 ShortDescr: Checking in the following graphics:

 CodeReview: 
 CodeReview: Result: @result___
 ====================================
 Changelist: 808273
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: B
 ShortDescr: Hello

 CodeReview: Result: 
 ====================================
 Changelist: 808271
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: C
 ShortDescr: HI

 CodeReview: 
 ====================================
 Changelist: 808298
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: A
 ShortDescr: Checking in the following graphics:

 CodeReview: 
 CodeReview: Result: @result___
 ====================================
 Changelist: 808273
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: B
 ShortDescr: Hello

 CodeReview: Result:  
 ====================================
  Changelist: 808277
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: D
 ShortDescr: HEY

 CodeReview: 
 ====================================
```

output.txt

```
====================================
 Changelist: 808298
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: A
 ShortDescr: Checking in the following graphics:

 CodeReview: 
 CodeReview: Result: @result___
 ====================================
 Changelist: 808273
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: B
 ShortDescr: Hello

 CodeReview: Result: 
 ====================================
 Changelist: 808271
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: C
 ShortDescr: HI

 CodeReview: 
 ====================================
  Changelist: 808277
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: D
 ShortDescr: HEY

 CodeReview: 
 ====================================
```

Comment: You don't mention for what OS this question is.

Comment: Windows.. i can take answer in bash, sed or awk..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you don't care about whitespace, because in fact your `Changelist: 808273` records are different (select text to see difference):

- First one:

  ```
  CodeReview: Result:
  ```

  one space after the colon
- Second one:

  ```
   CodeReview: Result:
  ```

  two spaces after the colon

Here is the PowerShell script that will remove duplicates from your data:

```powershell
# Setup input and output files
$InFile = '.\Data.txt'
$OutFile = '.\Output.txt'

# Separator to split records
$Separator = '^=+$'

# Read file to array and trim strings
# https://mjolinor.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/another-take-on-using-the-operator/
$Reader = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $InFile -ErrorAction Stop
$Data = while(($line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null){$line.Trim()}
$Reader.Close()
$Reader.Dispose()

# Find start and end indexes of each record
$RecordBounds = 0..($Data.Length-1) | Where-Object {$Data[$_] -match $Separator}

# Split records into multidimensional array
$Records = @()
for ($i=0 ; $i -lt ($RecordBounds.Length-1) ; $i++)
{
    $Records += ,($Data[($RecordBounds[$i]+1)..($RecordBounds[$i+1]-1)])
}

# Get actual separator string to use it in new file
$LiteralSeparator = $Data | Where-Object {$_ -match $Separator} | Select-Object -First 1

# Get only unique records, combine with separators
$Result = ,$LiteralSeparator + ($Records | Select-Object -Unique | ForEach-Object {$_ ; $LiteralSeparator})

# Write result to file
$Result | Out-File -LiteralPath $OutFile -Encoding Default -Force
```

Example result:

```
====================================
Changelist: 808298
Date: 2015/03/19
Developer: A
ShortDescr: Checking in the following graphics:

CodeReview:
CodeReview: Result: @result___
====================================
Changelist: 808273
Date: 2015/03/19
Developer: B
ShortDescr: Hello

CodeReview: Result:
====================================
Changelist: 808271
Date: 2015/03/19
Developer: C
ShortDescr: HI

CodeReview:
====================================
Changelist: 808277
Date: 2015/03/19
Developer: D
ShortDescr: HEY

CodeReview:
====================================
```

Comment: I think the goal is to only check for `Changelist: xxxxxx` and not the rest of the block. This solution will check the whole entry. In the example `Changelist: 808298` happens to have exactly the same text but if the Date and Developer etc. are different this solution will fail. Is it possible to use `Select-Object -Unique` and check for only the first X characters???? (I also get an error with LiteralPath but maybe that's just me and the way I run this script)

Comment: Okay, never mind. Apparently the blocks **are** always completely identical including the Date, Developer and descriptions.